# whats wrong with script it is not printing valid output in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using below script in that

```
 remote_conn.send("ping 10.10.10.1 vrf us-dc source 10.10.10.249\n")
```

is sending as

```
ping 10.10.10.1 vrf us-dc source 10.10.10.2$
```

I am wondering why it is sending $ at the end .

For other IP's it is printing properly. example

```
ping 10.10.10.1 vrf us-dc source 10.10.10.255
```

I just printed before sending

```
 ping 172.16.34.48 vrf us-dc source 10.10.10.249 # printed before remote_conn.send so its properly printing.  

when i used with remote_conn.send it is not sending proper output

 ping 172.16.34.32 vrf us-dc source 10.10.10.2$
```

I dont know what I did wrong in below script

Note for security reasons. I have not pasted here actual used IP's

```
import paramiko
import re
import time
hostname = "10.10.10.1"
net_username = ""
net_password = ""
remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
     paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(hostname, username=net_username, password=net_password,look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print(resp)
remote_conn.send("\n")
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print(resp)
remote_conn.send("ping 10.10.10.1 vrf us-dc source 10.10.10.249\n")
time.sleep(2)
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print resp
remote_conn.send("ping 10.10.10.10\n")
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print resp
remote_conn.send("show bgp\n")
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print resp
```

Comment: Save the string you are trying to `send` and print it separately to see what it displays. By the way, you could write a function for the receiving of the buffer. You are repeating the same piece of code several times.

Comment: sure and I need to use function its just testing elena

Comment: @elena added in question

Comment: Strange. Do you see the wrong output from the `remote_conn.send("ping 10.10.10.1 vrf us-dc source 10.10.10.249\n")` call?

Comment: @elena, yes its strange only when i am calling it having issues

Comment: replace that 249 with some other number. 248?

Comment: i replaced it is not working. ping ip and source ip i used differntly now it is printing properly like this ping 10.100.100.1 vrf T200 source 10.10.10..249